# React app is unable to handle svg images on Windows only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a react app that works fine on OSX, but it's dying on Windows, because of svgs:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="...">
```

I suspect the problem lies in a difference of regex opinion between the two operating systems (or maybe a different interpretation of slashes? Paths?) but that's only because I otherwise have no idea what went wrong.

Perhaps relevant from one of several .svg loaders in the webpack:

```
test: /\.svg$/,
include: /src\/assets/,
exclude: /src\/assets\/images/,
```

I realize this isn't much to go on, but I don't know what else to include. If there's any other information that would be helpful, I'll be happy to edit the question.

Again, the application builds fine on OSX. It just won't build on Windows.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but [create-react-app 2.0 came out yesterday](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/01/create-react-app-v2.html), and one of the features about which I'm the most excited is that SVGs can now be imported as react components. I haven't played with it myself yet, but it's a lead: [Github: Create React App - Adding SVGs](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-svgs)

Comment: That's pretty interesting. It would be nice if svgs could stop being such a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *was* the slashes.

This doesn't work on Windows:

```
test: /\.svg$/,
include: /src\/assets/,
exclude: /src\/assets\/images/,
```

This *does* work:

```
test: /\.svg$/,
include: /src(\/|\\)assets/,
exclude: /src(\/|\\)assets\/images/,
```

Forward slash *or* backslash. Also doesn't appear to break anything on OSX/Linux

Cribbed from [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4100)

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Also, that regex looks like your process is taking a while :)

Comment: Care to elaborate? I didn't write most of the webpack, but I'm always looking to make it less stupid.

Comment: Oh, just that the slashes kinda “roll forward,” like sprites bar on a command line interface. I meant no insult, just wanted to share my amusement.